# Enum deserialization using @JsonValue does not works for int values. It is using Index value instead of actual value

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Enum conversion done using **`@JsonValue`** is not working for **int** values in jackson. 
During conversion it is using enum index value instead of actual value. **`@JsonValue`** attribute is working for String enums

**I am using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE**

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity enumTest(@RequestBody Request request ){
        log.info(request.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
```

**Request Object**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Request {
    private IntEnum intEnum;
    private  StringEnum stringEnum;
}
```

**String Enum**
//@jsonValue is working for StringEnum Class

```
public enum  StringEnum {

    FIRST("first"),SECOND("second");
    @JsonValue
    private final String stringValue;
        StringEnum(String second) {
        this.stringValue=second;
    }
}
```

**Int Enum**

```
public enum IntEnum {
    ONE(1), TEN(10);    
    @JsonValue
    private final int intValue;    
    IntEnum(int i) {
        this.intValue = i;    
    }
}
```

`@jsonValue` is not working for intEnum Class,

If i pass 1 in request it correctly converts to enum value `ONE` BUT but if i pass 10 in request it say

```
index value outside legal index range [0..1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.demo.IntEnum` from number 10: index value outside legal index range [0..1]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.Request[\"intEnum\"])",
```

json  request

```
{
    "intEnum":10,
    "stringEnum":"first" 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Was able to get it working using **`@JsonCreator`**
**For @JsonValue with integer** We need to explicitly add  JsonCreator

```
public enum IntEnum {
    ONE(1), TEN(10);

    @JsonValue
    private final int intValue;

    IntEnum(int i) {
        this.intValue = i;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static IntEnum fromNumber(int number) {
        for (IntEnum b : IntEnum.values()) {
            if (b.intValue == number) {
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to see 10 for intenum, if you use same input to deserialize as Request and write back that request as writevalueAsString ?